# Could not create unique index-key("id", date) is duplicated

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, primary-key

I am trying to create a primary key using two columns(both columns would serve as the primary key).The columns that I am using are the "id" and "date" column. The "id" column DOES have duplicates but the date column is logs that formulate every hour so I am almost positive it does not have any duplicates, which is why I want both columns to serve as the primary key collectively. When I am trying to declare the primary key on both of these columns it throws me this error:

> ERROR:  could not create unique index "minuteSleep_pkey"
>
> DETAIL:  Key ("Id", date)=(4702921684, 2016-05-07 00:06:00-04) is duplicated.
>
> SQL state: 23505**

This is the code I am using

```
ALTER TABLE public."minuteSleep"
ADD PRIMARY KEY ("Id","date");
```

I tried the above code, assuming I could just simply alter the table and add the primary key to both of the columns. I am almost certain that this table does not have any duplicates because the table is just filled with logs that formulate every hour so it would be almost impossible to have a duplicate if a log is formulated with a timestamp every hour. The data type on the data column uses the date and time zone. Should I do a foreign key on one and the primary key on the other? Someone please help

Comment: The error message gives you (at least one of the) the id/date tuple that is duplicated. You can just `select * from minuteSleep where id = ... and date = ...` to bring the offending rows.

Comment: [Why should I tag my "RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) I added the `postgresql` tag based on the error message.

Answer (score 0):

A Primary Key can not have any duplicates
From [W3Schools:](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP#:%7E:text=A%20table%20can%20have%20only,or%20multiple%20columns%20(fields).)

> The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a table.
> Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values, and cannot contain NULL values.
> A table can have only ONE primary key; and in the table, this primary key can consist of single or multiple columns (fields).

I believe once you take care of the duplicate ID, your code should work.

`"(Id", date)=(4702921684, 2016-05-07 00:06:00-04)`